# How to call two widgets separately from StatelessWIdget that is in another dart file

Tags: flutter, class, dart, statelesswidget

So I am new to Flutter and I want to make a simple scoreboard with its timer and everything.  The problem is that I got two files screen_result and time. In screen_result I have a screen and buttons to operate the scoreboard, in time I have a stopwatch and its control buttons in it.

What I want is to call separately widget build Time below score and widget build Buttons next to other buttons for controlling scoreboard. I do that but nothing happens when I press button to start time. So I am doing something wrong but don't know what.

screen_result.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'time.dart';

class Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenState createState() => _ScreenState();
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
  int result_home = 0;
  int result_away = 0;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        //ROW 1
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          //-------------------------RESULT HOME
          Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            height: 500,
            width: 300,
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: new Text(
              '$result_home',
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 100.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //------------------------TIME SPACE
          Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                height: 150,
                width: 450,
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: new Text(
                  ':',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 100.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                height: 350,
                width: 450,
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: TimeState().buiildTime(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          //-------------------------------RESULT AWAY
          Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            height: 500,
            width: 300,
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: new Text(
              '$result_away',
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 100.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Row(//ROW 2
          children: [
        Flexible(
          fit: FlexFit.tight,
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 200,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 150,
                    height: 100,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.yellow[700],
                        onPrimary: Colors.red,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          result_home++;
                        });
                      },
                      child: new Text(
                        "GOAL HOME",
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 150,
                    height: 100,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.yellow[700],
                        onPrimary: Colors.red,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (result_home > 0) {
                          setState(() {
                            result_home--;
                          });
                        }
                      },
                      child: new Text(
                        "NO GOAL",
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
        ),

        Flexible(
          fit: FlexFit.tight,
          flex: 1,
          child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 150,
                    height: 100, 
                    child: TimeState().buildButtons()
                  ),
                  
                ],
              ),
        ),


        Flexible(
          fit: FlexFit.tight,
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 200,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 150, 
                    height: 100, 
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.yellow[700],
                        onPrimary: Colors.red,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          result_away++;
                        });
                      },
                      child: new Text(
                        "GOAL AWAY",
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 150,
                    height: 100,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.yellow[700],
                        onPrimary: Colors.red,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (result_away > 0) {
                          setState(() {
                            result_away--;
                          });
                        }
                      },
                      child: new Text(
                        "NO GOAL",
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
        ),
      ]),
    ])));
  }
}
```

time.dart

```
    import 'dart:async';
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'button.dart';
    
    
    class Time extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<Time> createState() => TimeState();
    }
    
    class TimeState extends State<Time> {
      Duration duration = Duration();
      Timer? timer;
    
      late String time;
       final myController = TextEditingController();
      
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        reset();
      }
    
      void reset() {
        setState(() => duration = Duration());
      }
    
      void addTime() {
        final addSeconds = 1;
    
        setState(() {
          final seconds = duration.inSeconds + addSeconds;
    
          duration = Duration(seconds: seconds);
          time = duration.toString();
        });
      }
    
      void startTimer({bool resets = true}) {
        if (resets) {
          reset();
        }
    
        timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => addTime());
      }
    
      void stopTimer({bool resets = true}) {
        if (resets) {
          reset();
        }
    
        setState(() {
          timer?.cancel();
        });
      }
    
      void firstHalfEnd() {
        setState(() => duration = Duration(minutes: 45, seconds: 00));
        stopTimer(resets: false);
      }
    
    
      void secondHalfEnd() {
        setState(() => duration = Duration(minutes: 90, seconds: 00));
        stopTimer(resets: false);
      }
    
      void addMinute (){
    
    setState(() {
     duration = duration + Duration(minutes: 1);
    });
    
      }
    
      void subtractMinute (){
    
    setState(() {
     duration = duration - Duration(minutes: 1);
    });
    
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
            backgroundColor:
                Colors.green, 
            body: Center(
                child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                buiildTime(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ), 
                buildButtons()
              ],
            )),
          );
    
      Widget buiildTime() {
        String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(
            2, '0'); // pretvara jednoznamenkaste brojeve u "dvoznamenkaste" 9 -> 09
        final minutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(100));
        final seconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    
        return Text(
          '$minutes:$seconds',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          
        );
      }
    
      Widget buildButtons() {
        bool time_going = timer == null ? false : timer!.isActive;
        bool time_stops = duration.inSeconds == 0;
       
    
        return time_going || !time_stops
            ? Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      ButtonWidget(
                          text: time_going ? 'PAUSE' : 'RESUME',
                          onClicked: () {
                            if (time_going) {
                              stopTimer(resets: false);
                            } else {
                              startTimer(resets: false);
                            }
                          }),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 12,
                      ),
                      ButtonWidget(text: "RESET", onClicked:  reset,),
                    ],
                  ),
                   SizedBox(
                        
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                  Row(
                    
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ButtonWidget(
                        text : '1. Half END',
                        color: Colors.white,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                        onClicked: firstHalfEnd,
                        
                        
                         ),
    
                        SizedBox(width: 10,),
                        SizedBox(
                        
                        child:ButtonWidget(
                        text : '2. Half END',
                        color: Colors.white,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                        onClicked: secondHalfEnd,
    
                         )),
                         ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                   
                   ElevatedButton(onPressed: addMinute, child: Text('+1 minute')),
                   SizedBox(width: 10,),
                   ElevatedButton(onPressed: subtractMinute, child: Text('-1 minute'))
    
                      
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              )
            : ButtonWidget(
                text: "Start Timer!",
                color: Colors.black,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                onClicked: () {
                  startTimer();
                });
      }
    }

button.dart

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class ButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      final String text;
      final Color color;
      final Color backgroundColor;
      final VoidCallback onClicked;
    
      const ButtonWidget({Key? key, required this.text, required this.onClicked,
        this.color = Colors.white, this.backgroundColor = Colors.black}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) => ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: backgroundColor,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32, vertical: 16)
        ),
          onPressed: onClicked,
          child: Text(text,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,color: color),)
      );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to `Flutter`, I would like to give you some tips.

1- There is no need to use the `new` prefix in the `Dart` language.

2- Instead, try to use `const` where needed.

3- To name variables, prefer `camelCase`, not `snake_case`.

4- Prefer `SizedBox` over `Container` when you need to assign `height` or `width` only.

5- Check `default` values, and try not to override properties unnecessarily.

6- Prefer to use `interpolation` to compose strings and values. So do not use `toString`.

7- You should make your Child's widgets(`Time`, `Button`) stateless, as their states are handled by the parent(`Screen`).

If we come to the problem that you faced, you are calling a widget from another State like the following:

```
child: TimeState().buiildTime(),
```

Instead, create separate widgets for different needs like you did in `button.dart`.

So take all your `addTime`, `resetTime`, etc. methods and put in to `screen.dart` and create two different child widget(TimeScore, TimeControlButtons).

If you have further questions, please don't hesitate to write in the comments.

Comment: So you are saying to put code from time.dart to screen_result.dart? And then extract code from widgets BuildTime and BuildButtons and make two stateless widgets?

Comment: Yes, you have only one screen. So you need just one `state` and handle all `states` from it. You are doing fine with creating small parts, but they should not have their own `state`. Also, those `methods` should stay in `screen_result.dart` because you are using `setState`, but you can send those `method's references` through the `constructors` to related `child widgets`.